# qt malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted

Tags: qt, malloc

In my Qt widget I sometimes get this error:

```
malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted
```

It does not happen all the time but I think I have narrowed it down to when it starts.

I have a QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene and there I'm drawing lines whos points are stored in a vector. Reason for this is I need to pass this points to another library. Once I draw the points I have an option if I click on a line I'm prompted to another window where I can change the coordinates of a line.

```
ResizeDialog *dialog = new ResizeDialog(this);
dialog->exec();
delete dialog;
```

The above code is the code I use to open a new QDialog. I know if I use `this->close()` the
qt malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted does not appear but then I lose the instance of QGraphicsView. Reason I need to keep the QGraphicsView window open if I need to chose to add further lines.

Any advice on how I can eliminate this issue wold be helpful.

Comment: which version of qt???

Comment: Im useing Q4 at the moment

Comment: can you provide a more precise version?? And where does the error get reported? Again, be more precise

Comment: Qt 4.7.3 is my version. Error just happens sometimes. I cant get it at the moment. But once it happens it does not go away unless I use this->close();

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#dtor.QObject - that raw delete there is suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `delete dialog;`, use `dialog->deleteLater();`. I assume the small code portion is inside a slot of the object referenced by "`this`", and direct deletion is source of trouble as `ResizeDialog *dialog = new ResizeDialog(this);` affect the parent object `this`.

Comment: I have tried this but I'm still get the error! Is there anything else I should consider?